# NSMutableArray returns everytime last object only

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing one application. In that iam using the NSMutableArray for storing the database data. After getting the data from database into this array. I am performing the search operation on that data. In that time everytime that array returns last object only. But at the time of retrieving the data from database it retrives different data. So please tell me how to solve this one. Part of my code is shown below.

```
 -(void)searchData
{
    list=[db getlanguages];

     for(for i=0;i<[list count];i++) {
    databasefields *dbfield = [list objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",dbfield.lang);
}


}
```

In this code list is the NSMutableArray.I will assign the memory for that one. And st the property for that one.

and code for [db getlanguages] is below.

```
 -(NSMutableArray*)getlanguages
{
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM A"];
sqlite3_stmt *stStatement;
NSMutableArray *getdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbfile, [query UTF8String], -1, &stStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    databasefields *dbfields=[[databasefields alloc]init];
    while (sqlite3_step(stStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        dbfields.num=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 0);
        dbfields.lang=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 1)];
        [getdata addObject:dbfields];
        [dbfields release];
    }

    if (stStatement!= nil) {
        sqlite3_finalize(stStatement);
    }
}

sqlite3_close(dbfile);
return getdata;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code above. I think the problem is inside `[db getlanguages]`. How is the `[list count]`?

Comment: logging means.Iam a jr.iPhone developer.That's why iam asking.

Comment: NSLog(@"List: %@", list);   do this after list=[db getlanguages];

Comment: That print the objects address.Same address for all objects

Comment: That print the objects addresses.Same address for all objects

Comment: Thank U.My pblm was solved.Yht pblm is in getlanguages method.

Comment: Santhi madam,may i know ur skype id.Because i want to take some help form u.So please send me request to my id.naresh.katari.gallait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the following line

```
 for(for i=0;i<[list count];i++) {
```

to

```
 for(int i=0;i<[list count];i++) {
```

and try.

**Edit**

You are using a single object and that you are releasing that too..

Make your statements as follows:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbfile, [query UTF8String], -1, &stStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    databasefields *dbfields = nil;
    while (sqlite3_step(stStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        dbfields = [[databasefields alloc]init];
        dbfields.num=sqlite3_column_int(stStatement, 0);
        dbfields.lang=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stStatement, 1)];
        [getdata addObject:dbfields];
        [dbfields release];
    }

    if (stStatement!= nil) {
        sqlite3_finalize(stStatement);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any need for allocate the memory for getdata?

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate.. Only thing, you can `autorelease` that while returning the object. But you have to `retain` the array in  `searchData` method..

Comment: please tell me ur skype id.Because iam new for this technology.So i need some help from u.So please give me ur id or send me request.My id is naresh.katari.gallait

Comment: My Skype account is chezhian.kic

Answer (score 1):

```
for(for i =0 ?
```

you are putting two for in a loop?

`for i` should be `int i`

Comment: that one also gives same result

Comment: what is the NSLog and alss NSLog the [list count]

Comment: Nslog prints the object.For [list count] returns the number of objects

Comment: i know what it is.. i needed to know the values..that are printed in the console

Comment: [list count] print the 2 in console using NSLog

Comment: then there should be two lines of code for  NSLog(@"%@",dbfield.lang);  in the console..did you see it?

Comment: what did you just typed [S that shows the object value]?? are there two line of code in console for NSLog(@"%@",dbfield.lang); ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(void)searchData {

     for(databasefields *dbfield in [db getlanguages]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dbfield.lang);
     }
}
```

if that does not iterate all the items in your array, you will need to check what is being put into the array in [db getlanguages].

things to look for :

- adding the same object each time
- not returning the correct array

without seeing your code, it is hard to guess what your problem might be. perhaps add some of that, and i can update this answer.

Comment: sorry, I must have been typing when you did that. @Aadhira's answer looks good, however, you will also need to use `return [getdata autorelease];` as the last line of your getlanguages method.